# scrollIntoView loading on startup

Tags: javascript

I have a very basic scrollIntoView function that runs whenever I click a link in my navbar. The problem I'm having, is that when the page loads, it quickly snaps to the scroll location and then snaps back to the top. How can I make it so that it doesn't snap at the start of the page? Thanks in advance!

Here is one of the scrollIntoView functions:

```
function aboutUsScroll() {
var aboutUs = document.querySelector(".aboutUs");
aboutUs.scrollIntoView({ block: "start", behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

And here is some of the HTML:

```
<div class="navBar">
    <div class="navBarButtons">Home</div>
    <div class="navBarButtons">Gallery</div>
    <div class="navBarButtons" onclick="aboutUsScroll()">About Us</div>
    <div class="navBarButtons">Contact Us</div>
    <div class="navBarButtons" onclick="footerScroll()">Social</div>
</div>
```

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Any demo would be more helpful to identify problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could load the function after the page content loads:

```
window.onload = function() {
    function aboutUsScroll() {
        var aboutUs = document.querySelector(".aboutUs");
        aboutUs.scrollIntoView({ block: "start", behavior: "smooth" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jack, your comment made me realise I had another issue

Comment: If my answer fixed your problem, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer for future reference?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so far for everyone, but I made a stupid mistake. Within my js I have a window.onload function that was interacting with my scroll functions. I fixed it now. Thanks!